# Angular2 Multiapp application

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building an app which has two sections management and view, design is different and i would say concept is different.

Right now i am doing that in two different apps and since app is growing and I am having more and more common methods which are copied across.

I want merge them, and tried that with Lazy load

```
{ path: 'projector', loadChildren: './projector/projector.module#ProjectorModule' }
```

It actually works but the problem is that I want to replace app-root with app-projector when route projector is opened.

Because now when I Open projector it show ProjectorComponent inside of app-root.

Comment: Try [`Router.resetConfig()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#resetConfig-anchor). I played with it a bit, but didn't actually implement it "for real". Might work for you...

Comment: @Sasxa How it could help?